# Select multiple rows in displayed columns in SQL Server also NULL

Tags: sql-server

I do want to create a select which is able to select multiple rows into columns. When a year does not exist then display NULL values for that year

e.g. the table below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MPG_TABLE](
[Driver] [char](40) NULL,
[Plate] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[Type] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[Build] [char](6) NULL,
[Miles] [float] NULL,
[Gallon] [float] NULL,
[MPG] [numeric](8, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

fill the table:

```
insert into MPG_TABLE (Driver, Plate, Type, Build, Miles, Gallon)  
values ('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2010', 20000, 2100), 
('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2011', 30000, 2900),
('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2012', 25000, 2300),
('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2013', 21420, 2130),
('PETER', 'BBBB', 'LUXE', '2011', 22040, 1650),
('PETER', 'BBBB', 'LUXE', '2012', 24000, 1800), 
('JACK', 'CCCC', 'LORRY', '2009', 180040, 96005),       
('JACK', 'CCCC', 'LORRY', '2010', 220040, 100005),
('JACK', 'CCCC', 'LORRY', '2011', 240000, 100235), 
('ADRIAN', 'EEEE', 'LUXE', '2010', 19040, 1450),
('ADRIAN', 'EEEE', 'LUXE', '2011', 30000, 2200),         
('ADRIAN', 'DDDD', 'LUXE', '2012', 22040, 1650),
('ADRIAN', 'DDDD', 'LUXE', '2013', 24000, 1800),  
('JERRY', 'FFFF', 'LUXE', '2013', 2000, 100)
```

And now update the last column:

```
update MPG_TABLE
set MPG = (Miles / Gallon)
```

I have something like ths, but it does not show what I want:

```
select distinct c.Driver, c.Plate, c.Type, a.build, a.Miles, a.gallon, 
a.mpg, b.build, b.miles,  b.gallon, b.mpg, c.build, c.miles, c.gallon, c.mpg  
from MPG_TABLE as a left outer join MPG_TABLE as b 
on ISNULL(a.Driver, null) = ISNULL(b.driver, null),
MPG_TABLE as c    
where a.Build = '2012'
and b.Build = '2013' 
and c.Build = '2011'
```

The result should look like this:

```
                          2009                    2010                      2011
Driver    Plate   Type    Miles   Gallon  MPG     Miles    Gallon   MPG     Miles
JOHN      AAAA    4X4     NULL    NULL    NULL    20000    2100     9.52    30000
PETER     BBBB    LUXE    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL    22040
JACK      CCCC    LORRY   180040  96005   1.88    220040   100005   2.2     240000
ADRIAN    EEEE    LUXE    NULL    NULL    NULL    19040    1450     13.13   30000
ADRIAN    DDDD    LUXE    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL
JERRY     FFFF    LUXE    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL     NULL    NULL
```

How to create a select for this?

Comment: can you be please more clear about your result ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select Driver, Plate, Type
    , min(case Build when '2009' then Miles end) as Miles2009
    , min(case Build when '2009' then Gallon end) as Gallon2009
    , min(case Build when '2009' then MPG end) as MPG2009
    , min(case Build when '2010' then Miles end) as Miles2010
    , min(case Build when '2010' then Gallon end) as Gallon2010
    , min(case Build when '2010' then MPG end) as MPG2010
    , min(case Build when '2011' then Miles end) as Miles2011
    , min(case Build when '2011' then Gallon end) as Gallon2011
    , min(case Build when '2011' then MPG end) as MPG2011
    , min(case Build when '2012' then Miles end) as Miles2012
    , min(case Build when '2012' then Gallon end) as Gallon2012
    , min(case Build when '2012' then MPG end) as MPG2012
    , min(case Build when '2013' then Miles end) as Miles2013
    , min(case Build when '2013' then Gallon end) as Gallon2013
    , min(case Build when '2013' then MPG end) as MPG2013
from MPG_TABLE t
cross join (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))b(b) -- number of years you want to display
group by Driver, Plate, Type
```

But keep in mind one important thing: pivoting like this should always be done on client, **not on server**!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE #MPG_TABLE(
[Driver] [char](40) NULL,
[Plate] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[Type] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[Build] [char](6) NULL,
[Miles] [float] NULL,
[Gallon] [float] NULL,
[MPG] [numeric](8, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into #MPG_TABLE (Driver, Plate, Type, Build, Miles, Gallon)  
values ('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2010', 20000, 2100), 
('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2011', 30000, 2900),
('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2012', 25000, 2300),
('JOHN', 'AAAA', '4X4', '2013', 21420, 2130),
('PETER', 'BBBB', 'LUXE', '2011', 22040, 1650),
('PETER', 'BBBB', 'LUXE', '2012', 24000, 1800), 
('JACK', 'CCCC', 'LORRY', '2009', 180040, 96005),       
('JACK', 'CCCC', 'LORRY', '2010', 220040, 100005),
('JACK', 'CCCC', 'LORRY', '2011', 240000, 100235), 
('ADRIAN', 'EEEE', 'LUXE', '2010', 19040, 1450),
('ADRIAN', 'EEEE', 'LUXE', '2011', 30000, 2200),         
('ADRIAN', 'DDDD', 'LUXE', '2012', 22040, 1650),
('ADRIAN', 'DDDD', 'LUXE', '2013', 24000, 1800),  
('JERRY', 'FFFF', 'LUXE', '2013', 2000, 100) 


update #MPG_TABLE
set MPG = (Miles / Gallon)

Declare @cols varchar(MAX),
    @query VARCHAR(MAX)



select @cols=STUFF((SELECT ', [' + New_Col + ']'
   FROM ( 
        select distinct case 
            when COL='Miles' then CAST(Build as varchar) + 'Miles'
            when COL='Gallon' then CAST(Build as varchar) + 'Gallon'
            when COL='MPG' then CAST(Build as varchar) + 'MPG'
        end New_Col
        from (select Driver
                    ,Plate
                    ,[Type]
                    ,Build
                    ,CAST(Miles as varchar) Miles
                    ,CAST(Gallon as varchar) Gallon
                    ,CAST(MPG as varchar) MPG 
                    from #MPG_TABLE
             )a

        UNPIVOT
        (
            Value
            for COL in ([Miles],[Gallon],[MPG])
        )UPVT
     )a   
    for XML Path('')), 1, 2, '');

print @cols;

Set @query= 'select  * from 
    (select  Driver
        ,Plate
        ,[Type]
        ,case 
            when COL=''Miles'' then CAST(Build as varchar) + ''Miles''
            when COL=''Gallon'' then CAST(Build as varchar) + ''Gallon''
            when COL=''MPG'' then CAST(Build as varchar) + ''MPG''
        end New_Col,    
            Value
        from (select Driver
                    ,Plate
                    ,[Type]
                    ,Build
                    ,CAST(Miles as varchar) Miles
                    ,CAST(Gallon as varchar) Gallon
                    ,CAST(MPG as varchar) MPG 
                    from #MPG_TABLE
             )a

        UNPIVOT
        (
            Value
            for COL in ([Miles],[Gallon],[MPG])
        )UPVT
    )b
pivot
(
  MAX(Value)
  for New_Col in ('+@cols+')

) PVT   '




exec(@query)
```